# Split Netcdf variable and re-write the file

Tags: python, command-line, netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I have a netcdf file that contains air quality data. There are 4 dimensions:

```
time : 24 hours (midnight to midnight) 
level : 1 to 8 (this is the height in meters (0, 50, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000 m)) 
latitude : 1 to 400
longitude : 1 to 700
```

I want to make a new netcdf file retaining only level 1, deleting the other levels, as I only need the surface.

How can I do that ?

I tried to do this with [nccopy](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf_utilities_guide.html#guide_nccopy) command line but it reproduces the dataset. I don't know how can I delete the other levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hyperslab with [NCO](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#hyp), e.g.,

```
ncks -d level,0 in.nc out.nc
```

If you don't have NCO yet, but you do have conda, install NCO with

```
conda install -c conda-forge nco
```

Comment: Wow very simple ! This tool is awesome thank you so much it works perfectly. I used `sudo port install nco` to install it on my mac. Just for information can you explain to me what is -d ? I can't see it on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in cdo using

```
cdo sellevel,lev in.nc out.nc
```

Selects all fields with levels as required in a user given list, or

```
cdo sellevidx,idx in.nc out.nc
```

allows you to select by level index instead. Further details here:

https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/index.html#x1-1360002.3.3